# Is it possible to update data without actually removing the previously added data in MySQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-update, mysql-workbench, insert-update

Im tasked to update selected information however not delete the previous data added...How do I update without replacing the old data and is it possible to view it if necessary?
Heres a part of my code:

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mycon);

```
            string Query = "update mydb.client set clientLN='" + txtClientLName.Text + "', clientFN='" + txtClientFName.Text + "', clientMN='" + txtClientMName.Text + "', clientType='" + cmbTypeMembership.Text + "', clientMembershipType='" + cmbRates.Text + "', clientMembershipValidity='" + Days.ToString() + "', clientMembershipStatus='" + validity + "' where clientID='" + clientID + "';";
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Client Successfully Renewed!");
```

Comment: First of all -- remember that you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: I didn't see any `delete` statement. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: What if client name is `';DROP DATABASE mydb;--`?

Comment: @codroipo - not a very nice client

Comment: @jgf - what we're referring to with parameterized queries and the '; DROP... ' name is the risk you currently have for a SQL injection attack... you should also fix this right away.

Answer (score 0):

In sql, an update without replacing old data is called an *insert*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to keep the old values related to the client around for [backup, audit, some other reason].  Two possible approaches;

1) Keep a archive table where you insert the existing record (with a timestamp) before issuing the update.

2) Make you main table effective-dated (but your application will need to know how to deal w/ effective-dated records).